# jquery.get() - problem using data as global variables

Tags: jquery

Well, I've read a lot in the Net, bust still haven't found a solution to my problem:
I need to check if the content of a file is "nok" or empty ("") using the jquery method get. One of the things I tried (didn't work of course, but shows clearly my idea) is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
...
var captchacheck="";
$.get("/form.php", function(data){captchacheck=data;}));
if(captchacheck == "nok") hasError=true;
...
```

So please tell me how really to store the string from data into a global variable (or another suitable structure) so that the plain text nok could be used in if-clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.variablename` or in jQuery style `$.variablename` to assign and access global variables.

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.captchacheck = "";
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.get("/form.php", function(data) {
           $.captchacheck = data;
        });

        hasError = ($.captchacheck == "nok");
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot to both of you, guys! You helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable outside of the ready function, it will be a global. Assigning it a value without using var will affect the global variable. This should work:

```
var captchacheck=false,hasError=false;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get("/form.php",{},function(data){captchacheck=data;});
  });
//later...
if(captchacheck == "nok"){ hasError=true; }
```