# Global variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery, global-variables, global

I have been working on this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    compentecy = $('#competency_id');
    $('#add_competency').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/script.php', {competency_id: compentecy.val(), syllabus_id: 2}, function(){
            // competency = $('#competency_id');
            competency.children('option[value=' + compentecy.val() + ']').remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

in the $.post callback function, it seems that I can't access global variables. I tried [$.competency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677314/jquery-get-problem-using-data-as-global-variables) but it didn't work. I always get a "competency is undefined" error. I had to reinitialize the variable once again inside the callback. Is there a way to NOT reinitialize the variable inside the callback?

Comment: Albeit not being ideal, this *should* work. Is this the whole script, or are you omitting parts here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG. it's one of those days I guess. spelling of the variable was incorrect :P

Comment: Glad you spotted it. :) BTW, you should declare the variable first with `var competency = $('#competency_id');` to restrict the scope to within your function and its nested functions, otherwise it'll be attached to the global `window`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) like this:

```
$.post('/script.php', {competency_id: compentecy.val(), syllabus_id: 2}, 
  $.proxy(function(){
    this.children('option[value=' + this.val() + ']').remove();
  }, compentecy)
);
```

[`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) lets your determine what `this` is inside the callback, just for cases like this :)